# Enumerate Windows DNS Server Zone attributes via shell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, powershell

I'd like to use a command-line tool to list a (primary) zone's configured secondary servers, if any.

Dnscmd comes close with:

```
dnscmd server /ZoneResetSecondaries:[list of secondaries]
```

But, I don't want to clobber any current settings, I just want to review them.  PowerShell (even on Server 2012) doesn't seem to help.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I just found it.

Use `dnscmd server /EnumZones`

then parse the list of zones to get zonenames run `dnscmd server /ZoneInfo zonename` and finally parse the output for `Zone Secondaries`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most correct in that you can:

1. Enumerate the zones and look for the "Primary" ones
2. Retrieve zone info for each zone

I've previously [written about parsing `dnscmd` output](http://blog.iisreset.me/2013/11/powershell-wrappers-for-dnscmdexe-part-i-zone-enumeration.html) using PowerShell, and this should accomplish step 1:

```
function Get-DNSZones
{
    param(
    [String]$ComputerName = "."
    )

    $enumZonesExpression = "dnscmd $ComputerName /enumzones"
    $dnscmdOut = Invoke-Expression $enumZonesExpression
    if(-not($dnscmdOut[$dnscmdOut.Count - 2] -match "Command completed successfully."))
    {
        Write-Error "Failed to enumerate zones"
        return $false
    }
    else
    {
        # The output header can be found on the fifth line: 
        $zoneHeader = $dnscmdOut[4]

        # Let's define the the index, or starting point, of each attribute: 
        $d1 = $zoneHeader.IndexOf("Zone name")
        $d2 = $zoneHeader.IndexOf("Type")
        $d3 = $zoneHeader.IndexOf("Storage")
        $d4 = $zoneHeader.IndexOf("Properties")

        # Finally, let's put all the rows in a new array:
        $zoneList = $dnscmdOut[6..($dnscmdOut.Count - 5)]

        # This will store the zone objects when we are done:
        $zones = @()

        # Let's go through all the rows and extrapolate the information we need:
        foreach($zoneString in $zoneList)
        {
            $zoneInfo = @{
                Name       =   $zoneString.SubString($d1,$d2-$d1).Trim();
                ZoneType   =   $zoneString.SubString($d2,$d3-$d2).Trim();
                Storage    =   $zoneString.SubString($d3,$d4-$d3).Trim();
                Properties = @($zoneString.SubString($d4).Trim() -split " ")
                }
            $zoneObject = New-Object PSObject -Property $zoneInfo
            $zones += $zoneObject
        }

        return $zones
    }
}
```

Now you can list all Primary zones with:

```
Get-DNSZones|Where-Object {$_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary'}
```

You could then use the Zone array to automate the lookup for all the primary zones:

```
$PrimaryZones = Get-DNSZones|Where-Object {$_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary'}
$PrimaryZones |% {$out = iex "dnscmd . /ZoneInfo $($_.ZoneName) |find `"Zone Secondaries`" "; "$($_.ZoneName) = $out"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to leave an alternative to Mathias's already great answer, here's a one-liner that works with any version of Powershell:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject MicrosoftDNS_Zone -Namespace Root\MicrosoftDNS `
          -ComputerName DC01 | Where ZoneType -EQ 1 | `
          Select ContainerName, SecondaryServers
```

(ZoneType values for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc448936.aspx)

Edit: Duh, if using an older version of PS < 3, change the second element in the pipeline to

`| Where { $_.ZoneType -EQ 1 } |`

Comment: Simplicity at its best :-)